# batch file: start another batch using cmd as admin

Tags: batch-file, minimize

I need to start an application with admin rights from an user account in win 10. I use a batch file to start the command window cmd.exe with admin rights and pass a batch file to this one. Unfortunately I'm not able to minimize the cmd window (needs to stay open). It is always displayed in the middle of the screen. Is there a way to show the window minimized?

batch file: start.bat:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:administrator /savecred "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k """C:\Program Files (x86)\test.bat""" "
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/1346935/how-to-actually-start-program-minimized-in-windows-10

Comment: my problem is, that the cmd.exe has to call the test.bat and I have to use the "/k". start /min at the beginning doesn't minimize the window.

Comment: Then, why not `/Q` instead of `/K` ? The script need user interactions ?

Comment: @Zilog80, you mean `/C` rather than `/Q`, right?

Comment: @aschipfl Oups, i mistaken your comment as one from OP. I mean `/Q` for no echo, my bad, _"instead of"_ was a poor phrasing as `/Q` is a flag for `/C` and `/K`. And i should re-read. OP is more looking on how to keep the exec cmd minimized with `runas` and `/Q` is of the no use here. That should be something like `c:\windows\system32\runas.exe /user:administrator /savecred "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /C start /min c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /K """C:\Program Files (x86)\test.bat""" "` in OP use case. Note that the related cmd will still be accessible in the taskbar.